# Handling string variables inside collapse command

Tags: stata

Edit: I should have generated better data. It isn't necessarily the case that the string variable is `destring`able. I'm just being lazy here (I don't know how to generate random letters).

---

I have a data set with a lot of strings that I want to `collapse`, but it seems that in general `collapse` doesn't place nicely with strings, particularly `(firstnm)` and `(count)`. Here are some similar data.

```
clear
set obs 9
generate mark = .
replace mark = 1 in 1
replace mark = 2 in 6
generate name = ""
generate random = ""
local i = 0
foreach first in Tom Dick Harry {
    foreach last in Smith Jones Jackson {
        local ++i
        replace name = "`first' `last'" in `i'
        replace random = string(runiform())
    }
}
```

I want to `collapse` on "mark", which is simple enough with `replace` and subscripts.

```
replace mark = mark[_n - 1] if missing(mark)
```

But my `collapse`s fail with `type mismatch` errors.

```
collapse (firstnm) name (count) random, by(mark)
```

If I use `(first)`, then the first error clears, but `(count)` still fails. Is there a solution that avoids an additional `by` operation?

It seems that the following works, but would also be a lot more time-consuming for my data.

```
generate nonmissing_random = !missing(random)
egen  nonmissing_random_count = count(nonmissing_random), by(mark)
collapse (first) name nonmissing_random_count, by(mark)
```

Or is any solution that facilitates using `collapse` the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `destring  random,replace` and then the following works:

```
collapse (first) name (count) random, by(mark) 

mark    name    random
1   Tom Smith   5
2   Dick Jackson    4
```

But `collapse (firstnm) name (count) random, by(mark)` still generates mismatch error.

Comment: +1 Thanks. The strings won't be `destring`able in all cases. Sorry. I should have been less lazy in my toy data generation. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking on this some more, my `egen` `count` with `by` operation isn't necessary. I can generate a 1/0 variable for nonmissing/missing string variables then use `(sum)` in collapse.

```
generate nonmissing_random = !missing(random)
collapse (first) name (sum) nonmissing_random, by(mark)
```